# Process and append each line from string to a dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, slice

I am processing the input string `text` to get a desired output

**Current Code**:

```
def process():
    content = {}

    text = """[hsdgsaj]{\"id\": \"1\", \"@hello\": 12345}
[dkfld]{\"id\": \"2\", \"@hello\": 123456}
[dfgjl]{\"id\": \"3\", \"@hello\": 1234567}
[fd]{\"id\": \"4\", \"@hello\": 12345678}"""
    contents = list()
    char = '\n'
    for index in range(len(text)):
        if char in text[index]:
            contents.append(text[:index])
    # print contents
    for line in contents:
        line = re.sub(r'.*{', '{', line)
        line = line.replace('@hello', 'hello')
    # print line

    contents = line

    print contents

    return contents
```

I want to do by following steps:

1. Get each line in `text` seperated by `\n` on a newline.
2. Strip the initial part from each line (i.e., part within square brackets `[...]`)
3. replace `@hello` by `hello`
4. Pass final string a dictionary `contents`

**Curent Output**:

```
['{"id": "1", "hello": 12345}\n{"id": "2", "hello": 123456}\n{"id": "3", "hello": 1234567}']
```

**Expected Output**:

```
{"id": "1", "hello": 12345}
{"id": "2", "hello": 123456}
{"id": "3", "hello": 1234567}
{"id": "4", "hello": 12345678}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is your expected output (return) a list? Or is this the output of the print statement?

Comment: Just return a list or dictonary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for each line, you want to:

1. remove the leading square brackets & its contents: use regex
2. evaluate the dictionaries: use `ast.literal_eval` since they're valid python dicts (`json.loads` also works)

in one-line, using a list comprehension to generate list of dicts, like this:

```
import ast,re

text = """[hsdgsaj]{\"id\": \"1\", \"@hello\": 12345}
[dkfld]{\"id\": \"2\", \"@hello\": 123456}
[dfgjl]{\"id\": \"3\", \"@hello\": 1234567}
[fd]{\"id\": \"4\", \"@hello\": 12345678}"""

result = [ast.literal_eval(re.sub('^\[.*?\]',"",x)) for x in text.splitlines()]

print(result)
```

result:

```
[{'id': '1', '@hello': 12345}, {'id': '2', '@hello': 123456}, 
 {'id': '3', '@hello': 1234567}, {'id': '4', '@hello': 12345678}]
```

iterate on splitted text as lines, remove leading brackets and evaluate.

EDIT: now I realize I forgot about stripping the "@" char in the keys. Let's iterate on the parsed dict, this is cleaner:

```
result = [{k.lstrip("@"):v for k,v in ast.literal_eval(re.sub('^\[.*?\]',"",x)).items()} for x in text.splitlines()]
```

this yields:

```
[{'id': '1', 'hello': 12345}, {'id': '2', 'hello': 123456}, 
 {'id': '3', 'hello': 1234567}, {'id': '4', 'hello': 12345678}]
```

this technique is simple & safe, as it's able to parse key/values containing square brackets or curly braces. Full regex methods can't guarantee that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` with `json`:

```
import re
import json
text = """[hsdgsaj]{\"id\": \"1\", \"@hello\": 12345}
[dkfld]{\"id\": \"2\", \"@hello\": 123456}
[dfgjl]{\"id\": \"3\", \"@hello\": 1234567}
[fd]{\"id\": \"4\", \"@hello\": 12345678}
"""
new_data = list(map(lambda x:json.loads("{"+re.sub('@', '', x)+"}"), re.findall('\{(.*?)\}', text)))
```

Output:

```
[{u'id': u'1', u'hello': 12345}, {u'id': u'2', u'hello': 123456}, {u'id': u'3', u'hello': 1234567}, {u'id': u'4', u'hello': 12345678}]
```